# Which domestic flights depart from Sydney international terminal?

Tags: air-travel, syd

I am qantas platinum frequent flyer and like the international lounge better than the domestic one. I am flying mostly domestic to Melbourne. So far, I only found JQ38, which departs from the international terminal going to Melbourne (because the plane gets in from Indonesia). How can I find more domestic flights which depart from Sydney international terminal?

Answer (score 4):

JQ1 (Sydney to Melbourne), QF19 on Thursdays (to Brisbane) for a start.

How? Australian Business Travellers has a post on this very topic:

[How to get into the Qantas First Class Lounge on domestic flights](http://www.ausbt.com.au/how-to-get-into-the-qantas-first-class-lounge-on-domestic-flights)

> The catch is knowing which of Jetstar's many Sydney-Melbourne flights
>   to book.
>
> When you're browsing the Jetstar timetable online, let your mouse
>   hover over the small information icon next to the flight duration. A
>   pop-up flight box will show details of the flight, including the
>   departure terminal.
>
> Most Jetstar flights will depart from 'Sydney Domestic Terminal T2' or
>   'Melbourne Tullamarine Domestic Terminal T1', but the ones you want
>   will instead be flagged as departing from Sydney's International
>   Terminal T1 or Melbourne Tullamarine's International Terminal T2.